# combination selector - Plus selector in css not working

Tags: html, css, selector

May be i don't understand fully plus selector, 
What i want, when user click on radio button home, div one should get displayed, 
and when user click on radio button about, div two should get displayed, it did not work, 
So i strip down the code, where is the problem, with this code i accepted div one to get displayed as home is by default checked. But it did not happened, so i know where is the problem but i dont know why,

Please read the comment, in the code, as i said which line is giving the problem hint it's css last section,

**HTML CODE**

```
<div class="container">
            <input  type="radio"  name="option" id="home" checked />
            <input  type="radio"  name="option" id="about" />

            <div class="navigation">
                <label for="home"  class="link">Home</label>
                <label for="about" class="link">About Us</label>
            </div>

            <div class="display">
                <div class="one">
                <h3>This is first</h3>
                </div>

                <div class="two">
                <h3>This is second</h3>
                </div>
            </div>    
</div>
```

**CSS CODE**

```
.navigation {margin-top:20px;}
.link{cursor:pointer;}
/*making div display*/
.one,.two{
    display:none;
}

/*
###This line is not working## want to display div, if user click on radio
button
*/
#home:checked +.container > .one{
    display:block;
}
```

if you want to run the code here is the code pen link https://codepen.io/arif_suhail_123/pen/KvdWey

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.container` is not a sibling of `#home`.

To select the element in question, when `#home` is checked, you can use the `~`, which is the general sibling selector:

```
#home:checked ~ .display > .one
```

```css
.navigation {margin-top:20px;}
.link {cursor:pointer;}

.one, .two {
  display:none;
}
    
#home:checked ~ .display > .one {
  display:block;
}

#about:checked ~ .display > .two {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input  type="radio"  name="option" id="home" checked />
  <input  type="radio"  name="option" id="about" />
       
  <div class="navigation">
    <label for="home"  class="link">Home</label>
    <label for="about" class="link">About Us</label>
  </div>
     
  <div class="display">
    <div class="one">
      <h3>This is first</h3>
  </div>
      
  <div class="two">
    <h3>This is second</h3>
    </div>
  </div>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

The `+` is the adjacent sibling combinator. Which requires:

1. The elements to be siblings
2. The selector on the left of `+` is the first positioned element
3. The selector on the right of `+` is the selector that follows.
4. There must be no other elements between them.

In the following demo:

- Each radio was moved in front of the div it's associated with.
- Each radio is `display:none` since there's no need to show them because the interface are the labels.

### Demo

```css
input[name='option'],
.one,
.two {
  display: none
}

#home:checked+.one {
  display: block;
}

#about:checked+.two {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">



  <div class="navigation">
    <label for="home" class="link">Home</label>
    <label for="about" class="link">About Us</label>
  </div>

  <div class="display">
    <input type="radio" name="option" id="home" checked />
    <div class="one">
      <h3>This is first</h3>
    </div>
    <input type="radio" name="option" id="about" />
    <div class="two">
      <h3>This is second</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @user2860957 Um, the one you accepted doesn't work correctly. If you test my answer, you'll see that home and about will both toggle. The answer you accepted doesn't toggle about.

Comment: You are right the answer which i accepted don't toggle, about, but i don't think it has to, as i am going to add this line of code as well, `#about:checked ~ .display > .two{
     display:block;
    }` my main problem was, i was not able to select, according to checked button, accepted solution does that, that's the reason i strip down my code, and also mentioned in the question, after reloading the page, it should display me div one as div is checked by default, sorry if i confused you. your answer is good that's why upvoted it, but the accepted solution is the solution i am looking for

Comment: @zer00ne That wasn't part of the question, but ok, I updated my answer just because... :)

Comment: @ChavaG *"...and when user click on radio button about, div two should get displayed, it did not work,*" is part of the original question. My answer does display Home by default. And my answer will reveal the div associated with label as requested. Appreciate the upvote, I just want to let you know that the answer is not fully functional. Other users will see the accepted answer but won't be as savvy as you are. ;)

Comment: zer00ne, after reading your last comment, i knew i messed up my question some where, when i try to describe my problem, you are right i did type those lines, and he is also right i did not ask for it, in short it's me who left the impression in one line that i am asking for it, and in other line i don't actually care, I appreciate your help and i mean it, thanks for help. Hope you understand what i am trying to say in this comment.

Comment: @ChavaG crystal clear, my friend. Happy coding, sir.

Answer (score 1):

I believe for the plus operator to work the element has to be the immediate next sibling - So in this case the .one div would have to immediately follow the #home label, and the css would have to be:

```
#home:checked + .one{
    display:block;
}
```

The html:

```
<div class="container">
<input  type="radio"  name="option" id="home" checked />
    <div class="one">
       <h3>This is first</h3>
    </div>
<input  type="radio"  name="option" id="about" />
...
```

Answer (score 1):

> `+` Selector : The element+element selector is used to select elements that is placed immediately after (not inside) the first specified element.
>
> `~` Selector : The element1~element2 selector matches occurrences of element2 that are preceded by element1.

So,you must use `~` instead of `+`.

```css
.navigation {
  margin-top:20px;
}

.link{
  cursor:pointer;
}

.one,.two{
  display:none;
}

#home:checked ~ .display > .one{
  display:block;
}

#about:checked ~ .display > .two{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  Home: <input  type="radio"  name="option" id="home" checked />
  About: <input  type="radio"  name="option" id="about" />
  <div class="navigation">
    <label for="home"  class="link">Home</label>
    <label for="about" class="link">About Us</label>
  </div>
  <div class="display">
    <div class="one">
      <h3>This is first</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="two">
      <h3>This is second</h3>
    </div>
  </div>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The order of elements is important when using this selector.

So to use the ~ operator the element should be after the first part.

Ex.

```
input[type=radio]:checked ~ label {
    display: none;
}
```

The Html should be:

```
<div class="radio-groupe">
    <input type="radio" name="water" id="choice-2" value="more-than-8-cups-a-day">
    <label for="choice-2">More</label>
</div>
```

and not:

```
<div class="radio-groupe">
    <label for="choice-2">More</label>
    <input type="radio" name="water" id="choice-2" value="more-than-8-cups-a-day">
</div>
```